# Debbuging inside a function with R

Tags: r, function, debugging, tibble

I have a R Markdown code in R, in which a function is applied to a list of tibbles. That function transforms each tibble in many ways, and I want to have a closer look at these changes.

I placed `browser()` inside the function I'm interested in and using `n` and `c` to go through each line. However, there are many tibbles in that list, so it would be nice to go forward until the function is applied to a specific tibble.

Can I somehow set `browser()` to go to one specified tibble? Or can I reach the same result with another command?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `expr` argument to `browser()` to a condition.  For example.

```
thelist <- 1:10
for (i in seq_along(thelist)) {
  browser(expr = (i == 7))
  print(i)
}
```

will print the numbers 1 to 6 before stopping.  However, the help page says that it is usually more efficient to just use `if`:

```
thelist <- 1:10
for (i in seq_along(thelist)) {
  if (i == 7)
    browser()
  print(i)
}
```

does the same thing more efficiently.